# Cast to string won't let me use All() method

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Writing an input validation:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if ((string)value.All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c.Equals('_')))
```

The "object value" coming back will be the text from a textbox.  The error I get is:

```
object does not contain a definition for All and no accessible extension method 'All' accepting a first argument type 'object' could be found
```

Why can't I cast it to string and then use IEnumerable on it? It is a string beneath it all.

Comment: `((string)value).All(...)`

Comment: Precedence - `.` binds before cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast is acting on your entire statement, not just the `value` parameter. Wrap that in parentheses:

```
((string)value).All(...)
```